# C# modPow negative exponent trick

Tags: c#, biginteger, modulo, pow

I try to use `using System.Numerics.BigInteger;` and perfom modPow with negative exponent, I read documentation about Exception, that's why I did some trick

```
//a^(-x) mod n == (a^(-1))^x mod n
BigInteger tmp = BigInteger.ModPow(BigInteger.Divide(BigInteger.One, a), 
                 secretKey, pCommon);
BigInteger resBigInteger = BigInteger.Multiply(b, tmp);
```

But tmp is 0. How I can resolve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "trick" is only fooling yourself. `BigInteger.Divide(BigInteger.One, a)` is almost always zero unless `a` is 1. In any event, this is not how to compute modular inverses. You must implement the Extended Euclidean algorithm, or, if you have the complete factorization of `pCommon` you can compute `a`<sup>Φ(pCommon) - 1</sup> == `a`<sup>-1</sup> mod `pCommon`, where Φ(n) is the [euler totient function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient).